# C# Кодировка Uri в WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

url содержит кириллицу, изначально закодированную в HEX - %20%2B%A0 и тд. Так вот если сделать WebRequest.Create(url), то в RequestUri будет декодированный url - с кириллицей, а мне нужна изначальная строка с хексом. Как этому глупому C# объяснить, что мне нужно сделать запрос по моей строке? 
Для примера - Internet Explorer обрабатывает url как есть, а остальные браузеры сразу декодируют кирилицу. вот мне нужно как IE

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужны методы класса [HttpUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var txt = "Текст на русском";
var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txt);
Console.WriteLine($"Encoded: {encoded}");
var decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded);
Console.WriteLine($"Decoded: {decoded}");
```

Вывод:

```
Encoded: %d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82+%d0%bd%d0%b0+%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc
Decoded: Текст на русском
```

Для доступа к пути в самом запросе:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com?query=%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82+%d0%bd%d0%b0");
Console.WriteLine($"original string is: {req.RequestUri.OriginalString}");
Console.WriteLine($"absolute uri is: {req.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri}");
```

Получим вывод

```
original string is: http://example.com?query=%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82+%d0%bd%d0%b0
absolute path is: http://example.com/?query=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0
```

Comment: я это понимаю. url передаётся в хексовом виде WebRequest.Create("http: //example.com?query=%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82+%d0%bd%d0%b0").
а в RequestUri уже декодированный текст. Но мне нужно обработать именно хексовый запрос, а не кирилицу

Comment: @ke1evra что значит обработать хексовый запрос?

Comment: @ke1evra если вам надо получить строку, что туда передавалась, то `req.RequestUri.OriginalString`. Если вы про абсолютный путь, что будет использоваться, то `req.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri`

Comment: я же вроде бы понятно написал :)
url на входе и url на выходе РАЗНЫЕ. https://dotnetfiddle.net/seQq45

Comment: да блин, я знаю эти параметры, вроде не глупый. Я говорю что на сервер передаётся кирилица, а мне нужно передать без изменений. запрос идёт по RequestUri, а не по OriginalString. Яркий пример - Internet Explorer делает запросы БЕЗ декодирования (в адресной строке остается хекс). а опера мозила и прочие декодируют

Comment: @ke1evra так вместо последней строки напишите `Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------\nOUT: " + req.RequestUri.OriginalString);` или `Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------\nOUT: " + req.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);` и будут одинаковые, как я вам написал

Comment: @ke1evra не пойму я вас. Что значит передать без изменений? Ну, закодируйте закодированное ещё раз - сервер всё равно автоматом раскодирует.

Comment: господи как же у меня горит.... вы не понимаете то я хочу. зачем мне выводить в консоль. мне нужно HTTP ЗАПРОС сделать, а в консоль я что угодно могу вывести. откройте одну ссылку в IE и в другом браузере и поймёте. Это не сервер декодирует, это WebRequest корявый так инициализирует url

Comment: @ke1evra ваша задача у вас в голове. У меня в голове вашей задачи нет, я сужу только по тому, что вы пишете. Поясните, что вы хотите получить на сервере?